# Higher level math functions in ARM assembly with NEON

Tags: math, assembly, arm, neon

Hi im kind of new to assembly and im starting to get familiar with ARM assembly combined with the NEON coprocessor in some of the new ARM chips. One of the things I am not sure how to do is high level math functions like sin,cos,tan,exp,etc.. If I disassemble C code that has these math functions it seems that they are external.

Comment: Is this for iOS (iPhone etc) or a non-Apple ARM platform ? If it's for iOS then look at the Accelerate framework.

Comment: There are probably no such instructions, instead they're usually implemented as [high-degree polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series). You can disassemble the library code or search for libm implementations.

Comment: its not just for iOS and I've already had a look at the Accelerate framework and it won't do what i want. I have looked at a bit of code from a math neon library written in assembly and im pretty sure they used high-degree polynomials, i was just wondering if their was a better way or anything else but it looks like ill stick with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option for you seems like it would be to simply link the other libraries in your assembly project. I don't see any reason to recreate the wheel if all you want the exact same functionality.

If this is a learning process then I suggest you either start with something simpler, as it doesn't sound like you have the experience to tackle a problem like this, or look into the higher-degree polynomials that user786653 suggested.

Comment: but I only need two functions importing an entire library for two functions? Ya right. Instead i've decided to use some code i've found in a library that will do what i want. I definitely do not have the mathematical experience to do write this I was wondering is if there was a better way than higher degree polynomials just in case (im really looking for performance here) but the answer is now clearly a no so i will use higher degree polynomials

Comment: Definitely use a library (if you only need two functions this should be easy to find on the web). Writing *correct* floating point functions is for the select few.

Comment: Alternately, since your requirements are low and it seems like your application is simple, you can create a look-up table for the two trig functions you need. It will be be fast and easy.